# Background Image Not showing Up - HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an image set to be my background but what ever I do it will not display. I have double checked that my set up is correct. It is. I've also tried css. No luck there. Here is the css I have tried and the html I have tried:

```
<html>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<body background="images/background.jpg">
<td colspan="2">
<td>
<a href="images/menu.png"><img src="images/menu.png"/></a>
</td>
more code here...
</body>
</html>

<html>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-image:url(images/background.jpg)">
<td colspan="2">
<td>
<a href="images/menu.png"><img src="images/menu.png"/></a>
</td>
more code here...
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure why this happening. I'm sure someone with more insight can tell me why.

Comment: Does it work if you link to an external image rather than local?

Comment: Start with [validating your markup](http://validator.w3.org) and then look at your browser's developer tools' Network tab to see if the requests for the images are being make, what URLs are being requested, if they are right and what response you are getting.

Comment: No it doesnt work when i do local

Comment: heres a link to the website https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/csc110/index.html

Comment: What does the web console show for that file? HTTP 200 or 404 or ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by web consule

Comment: Where are your images located? Give us a full link to background.jpg such as `http://........background.jpg`

Comment: i also just changed it to a png nothing

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/csc110/Images/backgound.png

Comment: I figured it out not sure why it wont work with just the image name and directory but I used:
  
    <body style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/csc110/Images/backgound.png)">

and it worked...

Comment: now how can i strech that image to fit the whole page not just multiple images layered on top of each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just the raw html with the image, i.e.

```
<html>
    <body background="images/background.jpg">
        <div>Filler content so the body has some height.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This exact code works for me with a chump image I put in place of background.jpg

I believe you have a problem with something other than your image. Try validating your html/css/other code files to make sure you aren't getting stuck up on an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-image:url('images/background.jpg'); 
    }

</style>

<body background="images/background.jpg">
    <!-- All your code goes here -->
</body>
```

Please make sure that you put your image in appropriate directory
You can find tutorial on background properties here :)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWn1nWIFbV0&list=SPC1322B5A0180C946

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="background:url('images/background.jpg');">
```

Surely that should solve your issue?

Comment: didn't make a diffrence

Comment: Are you sure your image folder is "images" rather than "assets"? or that "background" is called "background" or that the extension is called ".jpg" and not "jpeg" ?

Answer (score -1):

it seems like your are missing the 'head' tag.

Comment: you dont need a head tag

Comment: head tag doesn't affect body?

Answer (score -2):

Even though you're missing a Head tag the code works.
Might be stupid, but check if that folder / image actually exist and if so, make sure its jpg and not png or something...